# Gridview paging not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` control which I fill thru c# code and want to do paging with code like this

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)     
{
 BindGrid();
 GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
 GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

The `BindGrid()` function is where I get the data source for the grid and bind it.
It all works nicely exept that I have to press twice in order for it to change pages.
What can I do so that it will page after one click?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code for `BindGrid()` or at least an outline of it?

Comment: Press meening click the paging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your binding order is not correct.. It should be like...

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)     
{

 GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
 GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
 BindGrid(); // Call bind here
}
```